# Creating a new list of csv columns for each iteration

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I'm trying to write a csv file that should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYT90.jpg). What I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydwI0.jpg), where all the data is output as two long columns. Here's the code.

```
import requests
import csv

item_dictionary = {'10350': 'Third-Age Full', '560':'Death Rune'}
item_ids = item_dictionary.keys()
url_template = 'http://www.grandexchangecentral.com/include/gecgraphjson.php?jsid=%r'

sites = []
for i in range(0, len(item_ids)):
    result = url_template % item_ids[i]
    sites.append(result)


def data_grabber(item): 
    url = item
    r = requests.get(url, headers={'Referer': 'www.grandexchangecentral.com'})
    data = r.json  
    prices = [i[1] for i in data]
    return prices


data = map(data_grabber, sites)

names = item_dictionary.values()

filler = []
for i in range(0,365):
    filler.append(None)


myfile = open('prices.csv', 'wb')
headers = [names[0], 'Percent Change', None, names[1], 'Percent Change', None]
wr = csv.writer(myfile)
wr.writerow(headers)   

for x in data:
    q = data.index(x) 
    a = data[q]
    percents = [100.0 * a1 / a2 - 100 for a1, a2 in zip(a[1:], a)]
    percents.insert(0, None)
    f = zip(data[q], percents, filler)
    wr.writerows(f)


myfile.close()
```

I think the issue is with `f = zip(data[q], percents, filler)`. It seems to write for `data[0]` and then again for `data[1]` beneath it, when I'd like it to make that two new columns. Does anyone have any ideas on how to correct this? Thanks.

Comment: You could perhaps provide a simpler, self-contained example that focuses on the problem and does nothing else.

Comment: I would suggest trying on a small example, and adding "print f" around wr.writerows() if you don't know what exactly this zip() line is doing.  Sorry for not being able to be more precise, but the sentence with the screen shots doesn't make much sense to me.  If you're "trying to write a csv file that should look like this", then that means you're trying to have two columns, but your program has six according to the header line.